# Always override function with different returning type

Tags: vb.net, oop

I've got this MustInherit class called ViewerElement, from which derive classes like ViewerLine, ViewerImage, etc.

Then, in the main program I have a collection of different elements (Images, Lines, etc.). What I want to do is something like the following:

```
Dim NewElement As ViewerElement
For Each Element As ViewerElement In Elements
    If blabla Then
        NewElement = Element.Clone()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Elements.Add(NewElement)
```

I'm getting desperate to implement this Clone method without getting errors. How should this be de done?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `ViewerElement` implement `IClonable` interface.
Then, in `Clone()` method you should create a new `ViewerElement` object copying all properties values (or changing them according to your needs).
`Clone()` method must return an object that can be casted with your type; then it's up to to you decide which values assume properties, wchis status has every single internal variable.

An example (written in C#)

```
public class ViewerElement : ICloneable
{
    private int a = 0;
    private string b = "";

    public ViewerElement(int a, string b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new ViewerElement(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Marco thanks for the answer, the problem I had was that I wanted the ViewerElement to have a Clone method, so that I could call it int he for loop.
But since the ViewerElement class was only an abstract class from wich derive ViewerLine, ViewerImage, ViewerRect, etc I was getting some problems. Your code gave me an idea and I could solve the problem.
I still don't understand why whould we implement IClonable, isn't it enough to declare the Clone method?

Thanks!

Comment: @curial: yes, implementing `Clone()` method is enough. Anyway if you implement `IClonable` interface you make a contract that you can use elsewhere. Maybe it's just a matter of style... ;)

Comment: @curial: you can define `Clone()` method as `abstract` and let derived classes to implement it...